# How can I use 3 different styles based on two unrelated triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a `Gridview.Column` where the style of the content is changed depending on the content of another column by a `IMultiValueConverter`. This part works as expected.

If the values of the two values are the same then the text of this column is LightGray otherwise black.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="New Name" Width="300">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding newFileName}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                             <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                 <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FileNameColorConverter}">
                                         <!--<Binding Path="Selected"/>-->
                                         <Binding Path="newFileName"/>
                                         <Binding Path="fileName"/>
                                     </MultiBinding>
                                 </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                 <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Now I have another property in this object that is bound to this GridView. If this is TRUE the text of this column should become red, instead of black, if it is false, the `FileNameColorConverter` should decide the style of the column, same as it is now.

How can I do this? I am at the moment lost, and have no idea where to put this logic, I am quite sure there is a way to have this also in XAML.

**Edit**

What I tried is adding another trigger after the first one, but it didn't worked for me, if this is the way to go, whats wrong with my code?

I added this after my first `</DataTrigger>` but it didn't had an effect.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
             <Binding Path="FileNameError"/>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple data triggers with exclusive conditions on same data work for me perfectly... Can you check if your `FileNameError` is `True` for atleast 1 item? And if are you changing it dynamically then are you raising `PropertyChanged` event?

You can try my code and see...

**XAML:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MultiBindingConverter x:Key="MultiBindingConverter"/>
    <coll:ArrayList x:Key="MyData">
        <local:Student Id="1" local:Student.Name="Test1" Active="False"/>
        <local:Student Id="2" local:Student.Name="Test2" Active="True"/>
        <local:Student Id="3" local:Student.Name="Test3" Active="False"/>
        <local:Student Id="4" local:Student.Name="Test4" Active="False"/>
    </coll:ArrayList>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush
                       x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                       Color="Yellow"/>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding
                                Converter="{StaticResource
                                     MultiBindingConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Id"/>
                                <Binding Path="Active"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="3">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Binding Path="Id"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public class MultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
    object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
           && values[0] != null && values[1] != null)
        {
            var value1 = (int)values[0];
            var value2 = (bool)values[1];

            var result = (value1 > 1 && value2);

            if (result)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack
         (object value, Type[] targetTypes,
          object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public bool Active
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Student()
    { }

    public Student(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Wow, you can see my mistakes ... I forgot to raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` for that property. Thanks, for that hint.

Answer (score 1):

Add another trigger after the existing one which triggers on the additional property with `Value="True"`. This should then override the existing trigger if the property is true, allowing you to set the column to be red. However, if the property is false the trigger will do nothing and the existing trigger's effects will be visible.

Comment: That was the idea I had, but it doesn't work for me. I updated my question with this code, maybe you can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I forgot to raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` for that property. +1 that you showed me, that I was on the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [GridViewColumn.CellTemplateSelector Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx).

Depending on some logic, the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx), you give the cell a different [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx).

Comment: +1 thanks for your support, I definitely will have a closer look at `DataTemplateSelector`